# What's the relation between website's traffic and Google Adsense revenue?

Tags: google-adsense, traffic, revenue, publishing

Are there some relations between the website's daily traffic and Google's Adsense revenue? In other word, Suppose the same Ad. will be published on two different websites, the first has average daily traffic 2000 visits while the other has only 100 visits. Does one click on that ad. on the first website will make revenue more than the second website?

I've got misunderstand with Google documentation and I need to make a clear idea about this subject.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps [How much to earn with AdSense](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9902), I think each ad should work either by clicks or ad views, I'm not sure if they can affect each other. I don't use AdSense so probably I can't give you the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google adsence provides a reputation to a website which have the ads, Like the website with 2000 visitors perday must have the good reputation and a site with 100 srely have a low repo. So the click through rate(CTR) i.e the rate of per click on the add by the user will vary on both. A website with good repo has better rate then the website with not that good repo.

Comment: @Omne The data on this url http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9902
Does not regard any mention about reputation!

Comment: It depends but logically if first website gets more traffic than second website, provided all else is equal then your first website will get you most revenue.

But if to take into account different CTR on both, where first website with 2000 visitors has 2% CTR and second website with 100 visitors has 28% CTR while all else is equal then second website will earn you more.

I don't know whether website's reputation (authority and Page Rank) influence on clicks' value but there's something called "smart pricing" which is a scenario when AdSense reduces value of clicks you are getting.